# diff between drop down and dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

While i am coding i have to declare dropdown value in to one variable which datatype is dropdown.

my code

```
DropDown ddlTaskStatus = Row.FindControl("ddlStatus") as DropDownList;
```

but i can't access selectedvalue from ddlTaskStatus

so i change my code to

```
DropDownList ddlTaskStatus = Row.FindControl("ddlStatus") as DropDownList;
```

now i can access ddlTaskstatus selectedvalue property......
my question is what is the diffrence between dropdown and dropdownlist........????

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dropdown is for windows forms a dropdownlist is for webforms

Answer (score 0):

['DropDownList Class (System.Web.UI.WebControls)'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the actual web control used for creating a drop down list on a page. Hence this would be the correct control to use and it does have the selected Value property as you rightly noted.

There is no webcontrol called `Dropdown` at all. It is very likely that the `Dropdown` class 
you were referring to in your code was the [Dropdown Ajax Extender class](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/DropDown/DropDown.aspx) of the same name.

If so, then all this Ajax Extender does is provide a SharePoint-style drop-down menu for any ASP.NET control to which it is attached. Hence to get the selectedValue property (if it exists on the underlying control), you need to get the instance of the underlying control.

Comment: i noticed in my code i add one exteral framework. i got intellisense dropdown  from  that dll reference...ya i noticed its windows combobox...